# Написал код связи с оракл базой. Как мне правильно написать метод запроса SQL?

Tags: c#, база-данных, oracle

```
Написал код связи с оракл базой. Как мне правильно написать метод запроса SQL ?

using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

    namespace CsOracleTutorial
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                OracleConnection conn = DBOracleUtils.GetDBConnection();

                Console.WriteLine("Get Connection: " + conn);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString, "Successful Connection");


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("## ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                    Console.Read();
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");

                QueryEmployee(conn);

                Console.Read();
            }
    private static void QueryEmployee(OracleConnection conn)
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads";

                // Создать объект Command.
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

                // Сочетать Command с Connection.
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Метод который делает запрос к базе MySQL
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="query">строка запроса</param>
        /// <param name="columnCount">Кол-во возврашаемых параметров</param>
        /// <returns>List(string[])</returns>
        public List<string[]> QueryList(string query, int columnCount)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnection());
                List<string[]> responseSql = new List<string[]>();
                if (IsConnect())
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                    //var cmd = connection.
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var sqlData = new string[columnCount];
                        for (int i = 0; i < sqlData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            sqlData[i] = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(i));
                        }
                        responseSql.Add(sqlData);
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                return responseSql;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Error.Msg(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Надеюсь это поможет

Comment: а что это такое?

Comment: это метод который получает ответ от базы входящие параметры string query = "SELECT * FROM uploads"; int columnCount = кол-во столбцов в таблице

Comment: Ничего не понял к сожалению

Comment: Думаю, большинство проходят этап написания таких "универсальных" методов. Со временем придёт понимание, что он фактически бесполезен: в полученных из метода данных утеряна информация об именах и типах колонок. Если изначально там были числа, даты-время, блобы и т. п. - нужно обратно их парсить из строк. Ну и исключение глотается.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали команду, но не вызываете метод ее выполнения.

Официальная документация [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand?view=netframework-4.8)

Вам нужно расширить метод QueryEmployee:

```
private static void QueryEmployee(OracleConnection conn)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads";

    // Создать объект Command.
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

    // Сочетать Command с Connection.
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;

    //выполнение команды
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //логика считывания
    }
}
```

Comment: Поправил. Мне кажется, Вам стоит потратить время и подтянуть теоретические знания.

Comment: Я разобрался сам, извиняюсь что не отписал сразу). Спасибо. Каждый день учу мат часть